# Integral of secant to any power

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

In my university website there is a PDF with some integrals and I found this formula for the integral of the secant function to any power:
$$\int\sec^nx \mathrm dx=\frac{\tan x \sec^{n-2}x}{n-1}+\frac{n-2}{n-1}\int\sec^{n-2}x\mathrm dx \,\,\,\,\,\,\, (n\neq 1).$$

I searched for it on the internet, but I couldn't find anything. I know that it works for $n=2$ and for $n=3$, but I'm not sure if it works for  any other power. Something like $n\in\mathbb N-\{1\}$ is never specified, but I assume that since $n$ is usually used for natural numbers.

Is that formula correct? And, if it is indeed correct, how do you prove it?

Comment: I have no idea (off the top of my head) if the formula is correct, but it looks like IBP and a consequence of the Pythagorean identity to me.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2650899/945884)

Comment: Integration by parts $\sec^2 xdx=d(tan x)$

Comment: Look up reduction formulae.

Comment: The question seems to have been thoroughly answered even though the "duplicate" question wasn't phrased quite the same way. In particular there is a reasonably complete proof there, in which it doesn't even seem necessary for $n$ to be an integer. In fact it's only the division by $n-1$ at the very end that requires $n\neq 1.$ But the question could be reopened if there is some really new issue that the answers did not cover.

Comment: @DavidK Thank you for finding that duplicate target.  I had intended to revisit this question a little later in the day, when I am done with students.  I am glad that you were able to find a good answer for the asker here in less time.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Credit Stefan for the find in the second comment. I merely decided it was good enough for a duplicate.

Comment: Indeed.  Thank you, @StefanAlbrecht.